# how to read row by row in a dataframe using a loop and return each value or pop out each value

Tags: python, azure, dataframe

How can I read row by row in a `Dataframe` using a loop and return each value or pop out each value?

**Example:**

```
id    name

1     abc
2     vbs
2     askj
```

Comment: Sorry is this pandas?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) dataframes

You can use [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)

```
In [3]: for index, row in df.iterrows():
   ...:     print('Index is: {}'.format(index))
   ...:     print('ID is: {}; Name is: {}'.format(row['id'], row['name']))
   ...:     
Index is: 0
ID is: 1; Name is: abc
Index is: 1
ID is: 1; Name is: vbs
Index is: 2
ID is: 2; Name is: askj
```

Iterrows is iterating over the index, row tuple. The row here is a [Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html).

```
In [4]: type(row)
Out[4]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Comment: I suspect this is not a pandas question

Comment: how to pop each values return the result

Comment: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'pop'                                                for index, row in dataframe_output.iterrows():
        print(index)
        molecule = index.pop()